# Computer becomes unresponsive if sleep is interrupted

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, freeze, sleep, case

I am running Windows 10 with a Gigabyte B550 motherboard and a Corsair Carbide Series 200R case. I am not using any kind of UPS or backup power system.

When I hit "Sleep" on the power section of the start menu, the light on the power button turns off and my hard drive begins spinning down. A couple of times, I have accidentally touched the keyboard while the hard drive is still spinning down, and this gets my PC to wake back up again, but in a weird unresponsive state that outputs no display and receives no input. The light in the power button on my case turns on again, but the power button itself does nothing when pressed or held, and my only option is to unplug the PC.

How do I prevent this from happening? Is this even what sleep is supposed to do in the first place? It is the first PC I have built.

Comment: Holding the power button down for like 5-10 seconds is more convenient than unplugging it.

Comment: Come on  man, I said that the power button does nothing when held in the same sentence.

Comment: Maybe improve readability by splitting the wall of text into paragraphs.

Comment: Quite a few steps to troubleshoot this. What have you tried so far? https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/topic/guided-help-get-a-detailed-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-for-your-computer-in-windows-7-3f6ce138-fc04-7648-089a-854bcf332810 Is the PSU strong enough? Is Hybrid Sleep on? This is not what sleep is supposed to do.

Comment: My power supply does 750 watts, plenty for everything onboard (~450 W). I checked in the advanced settings, and the hybrid sleep option doesn't seem to change anything whether it's on or off. Everything appears to power down fully either way.

Comment: And if you ctrl alt delete when the screen is black after sleep is interrupted? Are Fast Startup & Hibernation disabled?

Comment: Please [Create a Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html), post the resulting HTML file online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc) and give us the link.

Comment: Sometimes the power button may need to be held for 15 seconds or so to **force** shutdown. If that does *not* work, it indicates a problem at a very low level in the PC, e.g., hardware, BIOS or firmware: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/holding-power-button-down-not-turn-off-computer-59892.html and https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/pc-wont-turn-off-even-with-holding-button.2181764/ Also check interrupt timing, if settable.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, this is not a full answer but I don't have reputation to comment)
I am experiencing the same issue, and this is also the first pc I have built. I, however, am running windows 11. I am using the gigabyte b550 x v2 - so a similar motherboard to you. This leads me to think it is definitely a hardware problem or something to do with the BIOS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).